# Unable to pass form data through jqgrid

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring-mvc, jqgrid

I am new to jqgrid and facing below problem.What I want to do is user will enter order details in form.Those form details will be send to Jqgrid on from submit.Now the jqgrid will pass form parameter to Spring controller.Spring controller will process data and send data to Jqgrid.

`1) ViewOrders.jsp`

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
    href="/resources/css/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
    href="/resources/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jq(function{
    jq("#submit").click(function(){
        jq("#grid").jqGrid({
            url : '/Online Fund Trading/Overview/Order.spring',
            datatype : 'json',
            mtype : 'POST',
            colNames : [ 'Customer Id', 'Account Id', 'Order Id','Order Date','Order Amount','Order Units','Order Type','Fund Id' ],
            colModel : [ {
                name : 'CusId',
                index : 'CusId',
                width : 15,
                editable : false,
                editoptions : {
                    readonly : true,
                    size : 10
                },
                hidden : true
            }, {
                name : 'AccId',
                index : 'AccId',
                width : 15,
                editable : true,
                editrules : {
                    required : true
                },
                editoptions : {
                    size : 10
                }
            }, {
                name : 'OrdId',
                index : 'OrdId',
                width : 15,
                editable : false,
                editrules : {
                    required : true
                },
                editoptions : {
                    size : 10
                }
            } ,{
                name : 'OrdDate',
                index : 'OrdDate',
                width : 15,
                editable : false,
                editrules : {
                    required : true
                },
                editoptions : {
                    size : 10
                }
            },{
                name : 'OrdAmount',
                index : 'OrdAmount',
                width : 15,
                editable : false,
                editrules : {
                    required : true
                },
                editoptions : {
                    size : 10
                }
            },{
                name : 'OrdUnits',
                index : 'OrdUnits',
                width : 15,
                editable : false,
                editrules : {
                    required : true
                },
                editoptions : {
                    size : 10
                }
            },{
                name : 'OrdType',
                index : 'OrdType',
                width : 15,
                editable : false,
                editrules : {
                    required : true
                },
                editoptions : {
                    size : 10
                }
            },{
                name : 'FundId',
                index : 'FundId',
                width : 15,
                editable : false,
                editrules : {
                    required : true
                },
                editoptions : {
                    size : 10
                }
            } 

            ],
            postData : {
                AccId           : function(){return jq.("#AccId").val();}
                FromDate        : function(){return jq.("#FromDate").val();}
                ToDate          : function(){return jq.("#FromDate").val();}
                TransactionType : function(){return jq.("#FromDate").val();}
            },
            rowNum : 20,
            rowList : [ 20, 40, 60 ],
            height : 200,
            autowidth : true,
            rownumbers : true,
            pager : '#pager',
            sortname : 'CusId',
            viewrecords : true,
            sortorder : "asc",
            caption : "Orders Overview",
            emptyrecords : "Empty records",
            loadonce : false,
            loadComplete : function() {
            },
            jsonReader : {
                root : "rows",
                page : "page",
                total : "total",
                records : "records",
                repeatitems : false,
                cell : "cell",
                id : "id"
            }
        });
        jq("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
            edit : false,
            add : false,
            del : false,
            search : true
        }, {}, {}, {}, {
            sopt : [ 'eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'gt', 'cn', 'bw', 'ew' ],
            closeOnEscape : true,
            multipleSearch : true,
            closeAfterSearch : true
        });

        jq("#grid").navButtonAdd('#pager', {
            caption : "Add",
            buttonicon : "ui-icon-plus",
            onClickButton : addRow,
            position : "last",
            title : "",
            cursor : "pointer"
        });

        jq("#grid").navButtonAdd('#pager', {
            caption : "Edit",
            buttonicon : "ui-icon-pencil",
            onClickButton : editRow,
            position : "last",
            title : "",
            cursor : "pointer"
        });

        jq("#grid").navButtonAdd('#pager', {
            caption : "Delete",
            buttonicon : "ui-icon-trash",
            onClickButton : deleteRow,
            position : "last",
            title : "",
            cursor : "pointer"
        });

        jq("#btnFilter").click(function() {
            jq("#grid").jqGrid('searchGrid', {
                multipleSearch : false,
                sopt : [ 'eq' ]
            });
        });

        // Toolbar Search
        jq("#grid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
            stringResult : true,
            searchOnEnter : true,
            defaultSearch : "cn"
        });


    }); 
});


</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form:form id="ViewOrders" commandName="ViewOrders">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter AccId</td>
                <td><form:input path="AccId" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>From Date</td>
                <td><form:input path="FromDate" /></td>
                <td>To Date</td>
                <td><form:input path="ToDate" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Transaction Type</td>
                <td><form:input path="TransactionType" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><input type="submit" id="submit"
                    value="Get Orders"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>

<div id="jqgrid">
    <table id="grid"></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

`2)OverviewController.java`

```
package com.oft.controller;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.oft.service.OverviewService;
import com.oft.valueobjects.OrderOverviewData;
import com.oft.valueobjects.OrderOverviewForm;
import com.oft.valueobjects.OrderOverviewResponse;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="Overview")
public class OverviewController
{
    @Autowired
    OverviewService service;

    @RequestMapping(value="Order.spring",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getOrderView(ModelMap map,HttpSession session)
    {
        ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView("ViewOrders");
        modelAndView.addObject("ViewOrders", new OrderOverviewForm());
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="Order.spring",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody OrderOverviewResponse getOrderOverview(@RequestBody OrderOverviewForm form,HttpSession session)
    {
        System.out.println(form);

        List<OrderOverviewData> datas=(List<OrderOverviewData>)service.getOrderOverview(form, 1);

        for (Iterator iterator = datas.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            OrderOverviewData orderOverviewData = (OrderOverviewData) iterator.next();  
            System.out.println(orderOverviewData);
        }
        OrderOverviewResponse response=new OrderOverviewResponse();

        response.setPage("1");
        response.setTotal("5");
        response.setRows(datas);
        response.setRecords(String.valueOf(datas.size()));

        return response;
    }

}
```

`3)OrderOverviewForm.java`

```
public class OrderOverviewForm 
{
    private Date FromDate;
    private Date ToDate;
    private String TransactionType;
    private Integer AccId; 

//getter and setter
}
```

`4)OrderOverviewResponse.java`

```
public class OrderOverviewResponse {

    public String page;
    public String total;
    public String records;
    public List<OrderOverviewData> rows;
//getter and setter
}
```

But after submitting data I am getting message as

```
The server refused this request because the request entity
is in a format not supported by the requested resource 
for the requested method.
```

I have included `jackson` jars but I am not geeting what I am doing wrong.
Please help me out.

Comment: your ajax call expects json, so does your service provide data in json format (from above it seems not)?

Comment: did you get anywhere with these, it got me too..

Answer (score 0):

This is the predefined function in jqgrid which will bind the data to the grid
either its come from client or server side no matter.

```
 $('#yourGridId')[0].addJSONData(eval("(" + JSON.stringify(yourFormDataObject) + ")"));
```